# Mosquitto bridge broker, connection refused after connecting

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I'm developing a webapp that connects to a local broker (dyson), the problem is that I can't directly connect to MQTT protocol directly from browser, and I cant edit the dyson broker config to open websockets ports. So Im creating a new broker with open websockets bridged to the dyson broker. I've tested direct access via server MQTT to dyson and works well, I can retrieve data from it. But when I try to connect from my broker it connects and then throws connection refused.

This is my broker config:

```
listener 9001
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true

listener 1883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true

connection paho33095379815290
address 10.0.0.248:1883
remote_clientid paho33095379815290
remote_username VS9-EU-233232A
remote_password ******
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
cleansession true
try_private false

topic # both 0

log_type all
```

this are the logs i get:

```
135848336: Bridge local.paho33095379815290 doing local SUBSCRIBE on topic #
135848336: Connecting bridge (step 1) paho33095379815290 (10.0.0.248:1883)
135848336: Connecting bridge (step 2) paho33095379815290 (10.0.0.248:1883)
135848336: Bridge paho33095379815290 sending CONNECT
135848336: Received CONNACK on connection local.paho33095379815290.
135848336: Connection Refused: broker unavailable
```

Comment: It's been a while since I had access to Dyson kit (and the source code...) to play with, but try swapping to  `bridge_protocol_version mqttv31` to try v3.1 rather than v3.1.1.

Comment: What does the log on the other Broker say?  There should be a reason why the connection was refused in that Broker's log.

Comment: @jdallen the broker is running on the Dyson fan/robot vacuum, there is no access to the logs

Comment: @hardillb tested it with `bridge_protocol_version mqttv31`, same problem. Correct there is no access to logs

Comment: Its strange because I tested the connection via NodeJS + MQTTjs, and it works, but direct connection from broker, nope.

Comment: Ok, removed cleansession true and try_private false. and got more output. Now it says `Connection Refused: unacceptable protocol version`. Tested with all the avaible for mosquitto: mqttv50, mqttv311 or mqttv31. None of them seemed to work.

Comment: FInally connected succesfully setting notifications false, and bridge version to mqttv311. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Feel free to add the correct mosquitto.conf file (with explanation) as a proper answer and marking it as accepted as this will mean it will show up in searches better.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so basically this is the final mosquitto config:

```
log_type all

listener 9001
protocol websockets
allow_anonymous true

listener 1883
protocol mqtt
allow_anonymous true

#bridge
connection dyson-fan
address 10.0.0.248:1883
remote_clientid paho33135379815290
remote_username VS9-EU-KFA2511A
remote_password *****
bridge_protocol_version mqttv311
try_private false
notifications false
cleansession true
topic # both 0
```

For some reason, notifications to default true, which was making the Dyson broker unavailable.